# Get current date and time in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm developing a keyboard tracker to track all the keys pressed by the user along with time.

I found many blogs on `getnstimeofday(struct timespec*)` but it's deprecated in latest kernel version because of the "year 2038 problem on 32-bit architectures". Its replacement function is `ktime_get_real_ts64` but I'm not able to understand it.

Can someone help me to give the basic idea to implement it or if you can share the working code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use it pretty much the same way you'd use `getnstimeofday`:

```c
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/timekeeping.h>
//...
struct timespec64 now;
ktime_get_real_ts64(&now);
struct tm tm_now;
time64_to_tm(now.tv_sec, 0, &tm_now);
//tm_now is similar to the userspace tm
```